# How can I make a regex match the next 4 characters immediately after finding something?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to sift through a sizable amount of data.  After it finds something, I want it to match the next 4 characters whatever they are.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
/match long stuff here..../
```

The `.` in a regex is "Any character." Four of them gets you four characters. You could also do:

```
/match long stuff here.{4}/
```

This may depend on what language you are writing your regex in.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `....` matches any four characters. Append that to your pattern, and put parenthesis around it so that whatever those characters are will be captured.

For example:

```
[Hh]ello [Ww]orld(....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example: I want to match an IP and the next 4 characters after it.I have a regex

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(.{4})
```

if you match that against the following string `192.167.45.45xabc` the first part `(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})` will match the IP and the last part (.{4}) will match xabc. (I had added `?:` at the beginning to make the first block noncapturing - if you want to capture the IP to just remove `?:`)
I hope this helps